# Right - click menu events for simple chrome popup window is wrong

Tags: system, desktop

when i click `Always on top` ,`Always on visible` take effect,and vice versa.

[image: chrome simple window]

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: Embarrassed,my English is not good.

Comment: When I connect to my corporate's wireless network,system will popup authentication window automatic ,but this window is always on top and visible on all workspace,and when I click the title bar ,will show this popup menu.
The question is:
when I click item `Always on top`,it's not work,but `Always on visible Workspace` worked.that's all.
Wish I could make it clear.

thank you!

Comment: it's a chrome window? I don't have such options

Comment: oh,may be it's network window,because the icon in dock bar is network. but I open network config in setting panel initiatively,the menu is right.Only the auto popup window when I connect to network is wrong.
even if that's not affect usage,but the problem is real.I don't know where to feed this problem back to developers.That's why I asked if someone finds the same problem.Thank you for your kind reply ,and do you know where to feed back this question to developers?Thank you again!

Comment: added as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright this is not an answer, but if e believe is a bug you can submit it here
[github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aopen%20is%3Aissue%20user%3Aelementary%20label%3A%22bitesize%22&type=)